# Cursor.execute is not wroking

Tags: python, django

`cursor.execute(query)` is not executing in Django if I have entered tuple manual in oracle using sqldeveloper.

```
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            try:
                print(value)
                print(username)
                cursor.execute("Select * from users where id=1")
            finally:
                cursor.close()
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No Error But server is not responding on opening the URL.

Comment: this code is working when i insert data using django.But didn't worked when i entered data manual using SQL developer in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

use below code.

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * Table ")
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you got this error: `AttributeError: __enter__`.
This eror means you can't use statement `with .. as ..` with `conn.cursor()`

Comment: No Error But server is not responding.